# problems with exception in java app

Tags: java, custom-exceptions

Who could help me with exceptions, I have a task to make a small simulation of student app for university. So I have a log in page and in that page I have labels and text fields for `name`, `surname`, `adress`, `city` and student index book. I have to make a several classes for exception and main class will be `studentexceptions` and other will be subclasses in which I will have `nameException`, `surnameException`, `adressException`, `cityException` and `indexBookException`. What should I put in `studentException`? Maybe to make it abstract?

```
public class cityIsNotValidException extends StudentException {
    private String city;

    public cityIsNotValidException(String city){
        super("Name of the city is not valid "+city);
        this.city=city;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read, how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Java convention is to make class names pascal-case, LikeThis (capital first letter).

Comment: Yes, i know but iwas in a hurry to adit post cause i was translating name of the class to english,sorry .but thanks, i will check your solution

Answer (score 0):

If the point of `StudentException` is merely to differentiate between application-specific exceptions and general exceptions, then it may be empty apart of needed constructors.

If you do not want anyone to throw `StudentExcpetion` (only want to allow subclasses to be thrown), then make it `abstract`.